# PhpStorm - how do I turn this bar off?

Tags: phpstorm

I am referring to the bar in the picture.
It is the bar between the files open and the code editor.
It says `form`, `fieldset` and `legend`.

[image]

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable this by unchecking the `show breadcrumbs` option in the Editor setting. `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `General` -> `Appearance`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This are breadcrumbs that show you the current context (namespace, class, method etc.). You can disable them in Preferences | Editor | General | Appearance - untick "Show breadcrumbs" and press OK.